# Inverse function theorem - derivative has not full rank

Tags: analysis, inverse-function-theorem

I am a little bit confused... Suppose that the derivative of a function $f$ has not full rank at a point $a$.

However, this does not imply that there doesn't exist an inverse function. We can only say that we are not allowed to apply the inverse function theorem which would guarantee the existence of an inverse function with nice properties, right?

Comment: yes, that's right. An example is $f(x) = x^3$. An inverse function will, however, not be differentiable.

Comment: @Thomas, thank you, I haven't thought about this simple example. Is there an intuition why these inverse functions cannot be differentiable?

Comment: well, $f\circ f^{-1}(x) = x$ is for sure differentiable. If $f$ is in $x$ and $f^{-1}$ were in $f(x)$, too, write down what this implies for $d(f^{-1})$ at $f(x)$. (For simplicity I just made this claim for functions, i.e. in one dimension).

Comment: @Thomas, I am not sure if I have understood your idea right. Let be $f: \mathbb{R}\supseteq M \to N \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ invertible on a neighborhood of $a$ where $df(a)=0$ and $f(a)=b$. If we assume that $f^{-1}$ is differentiable then we have $$df^{-1}(b)=lim_{y\to b}\frac{f^{-1}(y)-f^{-1}(b)}{y-b}=lim_{f(x)\to f(a)}\frac{x-a}{f(x)-f(a)}, $$where $x \in M$ and $y \in N$. This looks like the reciprocal differential quotient of $f$ at point $a$ which would not be defined as $df(a)=0$. However, we take the limit $lim_{f(x)\to f(a)}$ instead of $lim_{x \to a}$. Or is this approach wrong?

Comment: Differentiate the identity (apply the chain rule)  to $f\circ f^{-1} (x) = x$ and try to figure out what it means for the derivative of the inverse function.

Comment: @Thomas, Ah okay, I think I got it: we have $df(f^{-1}(x))df^{-1}(x)=1$ but $df(f^{-1}(x))=0$ which leads to a contradiction because multiplying by $0$ yields $0$. Right?

Comment: yes, that's what I meant.